# Django ValidationError CSV-Upload

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file into my Django model. Although the upload of the data works fine (all the rows get copied into the database), at the end Django returns a `ValidationError ["'' value must be a decimal number."]` error message.
From the local vars section of the error message I kind of get the reason - when the iteration reaches the end of the rows containing data, there is obviously no decimal number. So Django throws an error. However, I do not understand why, as there is always a last row after which there is no more data. I fiddled around a bit to try to find the problem. A method that worked is so copy the whole data from the original CSV into a new CSV - there was no error message any more. I would love to accomplish the whole process with the original CSV file and no error message! Would appreciate any help.

My CSV files are CSV UTF-8 and they are saved in Excel

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Testdata3(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    assetclass = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25,decimal_places=10)
    performance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25,decimal_places=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Testdata3
import csv, io
from django.contrib import messages


def file_upload(request):
    template = "upload.html"
    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order of the CSV should be "placeholder_1", "placeholder_2", "placeholder_3" '
    }

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template, prompt)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')

    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=';', quotechar="|"):
        _, created = Testdata3.objects.update_or_create(
            key = column[0],

            defaults = {
            'key' : column[0],
            'assetclass' : column[10],
            'value' : column[16],
            'performance' : column[18],
            }
        )
        context = {}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

**upload.html**

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div>
            <strong>{{message|safe}}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{%else %}
{{ order }}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Upload a file</label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <p>Only accepts CSV files</p>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm sure you have checked this, is there an empty row at the end of the csv? You could look in a text editor to check.

Comment: Many thanks @brandonbanks! This is indeed the issue - any I didn't check for that as I did not know that this can cause a problem. Now I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the empty lines at the end of the CSV file. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: Of course! Glad to help. Nice work figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution! I included an if-statement, which checks if the current iteration has only empty values, and if yes it jumps to the next iteration

```
# ... 

views.py

    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=';', quotechar="|"):
        # Check for empty rows in CVS and jump to next iteration if empty
        if all(elem == "" for elem in column):
            next
        else:
            _, created = Testdata3.objects.update_or_create(
                key = column[0],

                defaults = {
                'key' : column[0],
                'assetclass' : column[10],
                'value' : column[16],
                'performance' : column[18],
                }
            )

# ...
```